# Remove a nested element from state with $splice - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, splice

I am trying to remove an element from the `Component` state. This is how the interested part of the state looks:

```
this.state({user:{
    ...
    instruments: [
        0: {
            name:"bass guitar",
            experience: "2"
        }
        1: {
            name:"drums",
            experience: "1"
        }
        ...
    ]
}})
```

When the user clicks on a button, I want to remove that element from the state. With the following code, the first element in the array is always removed, because splice cannot access the inner `name` propriety. Any ideas?

**Instrument.js**

```
remove(){
    this.props.removeInstrument(this.props.name);
}

render(){
    return(
        <article className="instrument">
                <Col xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <div className="container-elements">
                        <span className="delete-element" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>x</span>
                        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.experience} years of experience</p>
                    </div>
                </Col>
        </article>
    );
}
```

**EditProfile.js**

```
    removeInstrument(val) {
    console.log('clicked on remove! ', val);
    this.setState({
        user: update(this.state.user, {instruments: {$splice: [[val,1]]}})
    })
}

// this is how I render the instrument
<div className="container-tags">
   {this.state.user.instruments.map((instrument, index) => {
       return <Instrument key={instrument.name} removeInstrument={this.removeInstrument} name={instrument.name} experience={instrument.experience}/>;
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: a) Pass the index and remove by index, not by name, b) use `filter` to remove elements by name, i.e. `instruments : this.state.user.instruments.filter( instrument => instrument.name !== val )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that using the `index` of the data, rather than using `name`

**Instrument.js**

```
remove(){
    this.props.removeInstrument(this.props.index);
}

render(){
    return(
        <article className="instrument">
                <Col xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <div className="container-elements">
                        <span className="delete-element" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>x</span>
                        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.experience} years of experience</p>
                    </div>
                </Col>
        </article>
    );
}
```

**EditProfile.js**

```
removeInstrument(val) {
    console.log('clicked on remove! ', val);
    this.setState({
        user: update(this.state.user, {instruments: {$splice: [[val,1]]}})
    })
}

// this is how I render the instrument
<div className="container-tags">
   {this.state.user.instruments.map((instrument, index) => {
       return <Instrument key={instrument.name} removeInstrument={this.removeInstrument} name={instrument.name} experience={instrument.experience} index={index}/>;
    })}
</div>
```